Why is there a program called 'fucker' in my snap list?
Running:
snap list

on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine this morning, I noticed a program called 'fucker':
fucker 0.1 pyaesoanaung19


A quick google returns: this which doesn't tell me much:

question: why is this program installed on my computer? Is it malware?
Here is the output of running:
snap connections | grep fucker


further investigation:
I moved the snap (which is 158MB) to my desktop from /var/lib/snapd/snaps
and ran:
unsquashfs fucker_1.snap


this is what I see:

The only mention of it's name is in the /meta/*.yaml file:


Are you sure you didn't install it? Maybe you got annoyed and wrote snap install fucker, or misremembered thefuck? Edit your post to add the output of snap connections | grep fucker using [code block]s, please.

At the same time, I find this funny and disturbing. Since it's on your computer, you probably installed it. However, looking at the item in the snap store, I'm pretty sure it doesn't align with current site policy, and I've written a request to Canonical to take it down from the snap store. You should probably uninstall it with sudo snap remove fucker.

Please don't post screenshots of text. As I mentioned in my first comment, use [code block]s instead.

If you look at your bash history with history fucker, is there any indication you installed this manually? (Potentially by accident)

It seems the Canonical guys don't believe it's a problem. I still find it suspect, so just remove it.
